# JS or jQuery way to dynamically create DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Could anyone point me a more easy-to-read-and-expand way of doing this:

```
data = {/*very very long json*/};
var inHTML = "";

jQuery.each(data, function(key, value){
    var articleUrl = 'url-to-somewhere';

    var newItem = "<div class='item'><div class='item--poster'><img src='"+data[key].backdropUrl+"' alt='title'/></div><div class='item--content'><h2>"+data[key].title+"</h2><ul><li>"+data[key].productionYear+"</li><li>"+data[key].productionCountry+"</li></ul></div><div class='item--link'><p><a class='' href='"+articleUrl+"'>Lue lisää</a></p></div></div>";
    inHTML += newItem;  

});

jQuery("#container").html(inHTML);
```

What I'm looking for is something similar to ng-repeat of Angular.

Comment: You may put one piece of `very very long json` here for our reference.

Comment: Praveen Kumar, I dont think pasting it here would make any difference.

Comment: You can create element like `$('<div />', { "class" : "item"}).append($('<div />', { "class" : "item--poster"}))`

Comment: @Shamppi Have a look at my answer. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar, bravo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet on using placeholder template and `.clone()`. What exactly you need to do is, create a Master DOM like this:

```
<div id="master-dom" class="item">
  <p><strong>Name</strong> <span class="Name"></span></p>
  <p><strong>Age</strong> <span class="Age"></span></p>
</div>
```

Now give a CSS that would hide the Master DOM:

```
#master-dom {display: none;}
```

The next attempt would be, have a `#content` area:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

And now comes the JavaScript part.

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Praveen",
    "age": 27
  },
  {
    "name": "Jon Skeet",
    "age": 29
  },
  {
    "name": "Kumar",
    "age": 25
  }
];
```

Having the above as the data structure, you can loop through and insert:

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
  // We need the v.
  $("#master-dom").clone()
                  .removeAttr("id")
                  .find(".Name").text(v.name).end()
                  .find(".Age").text(v.age).end()
                  .appendTo("#content");
});
```

See the final output here:

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "name": "Praveen",
    "age": 27
  }, {
    "name": "Jon Skeet",
    "age": 29
  }, {
    "name": "Kumar",
    "age": 25
  }];

  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
    // We need the v.
    $("#master-dom").clone()
      .removeAttr("id")
      .find(".Name").text(v.name).end()
      .find(".Age").text(v.age).end()
      .appendTo("#content");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#master-dom {
  display: none;
}
.item p strong {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="master-dom" class="item">
  <p><strong>Name</strong> <span class="Name"></span></p>
  <p><strong>Age</strong> <span class="Age"></span></p>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

I really believe this would be the underlying logic behind Angular's `ng-repeat`. Also I would use this above logic if I were in your place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ES6 feature [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Your string would look like this

```
var newItem =
    `<div class='item'>
        <div class='item--poster'>
            <img src='${data[key].backdropUrl}' alt='title'/>
        </div>
        <div class='item--content'>
            <h2>${data[key].title}</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>${data[key].productionYear}</li>
                <li>${data[key].productionCountry}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='item--link'>
            <p>
                <a class='' href='${articleUrl}'>Lue lisää</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>`;
```